# Add a second line to main menu on Divi

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu, divi

I'm trying to create a 2nd line above the top main menu on WordPress Divi. I created the variable $secondaryNav to hold the 2nd line. I'm trying to replicate the menu from this page as an example: tractionondemand.com

With the code below I'm able to see the 2nd line above the top menu on the desktop, but on mobile, it's not integrating into the hamburger icon.

```
$secondaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass , 'menu_id' => 'top-menu', 'echo' => false ) );
                            
echo et_core_esc_wp( $secondaryNav );
echo "<br>";                        
echo et_core_esc_wp( $primaryNav );
```

What's missing or do I need to approach this in a different way?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The regular header on Divi is very limited. I would recommend you to use the **Theme Builder** option, on the **Divi** menu on Dashboard. Add a global header, and design it like you design a normal page with the divi builder.

You can create rows, columns, add whatever you need, and then save it. This header will replace the original one in all your pages, or only the pages you select.